# Atualizar duas tabelas com condição

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, query

Tenho o seguinte cenário
Duas Tabelas
Tabela Origem - Tabela Destino

Ambas com os mesmos campos 
[ID]  [Nome]  [CPF]

A consulta deve ir nas colunas [CPF] das duas tabelas, quando o [CPF] da Origem e Destino for iguais, deve atualizar o campo [Nome] da Tabela Destino conforme o da Origem.

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 7):

Embora você não tenha especificado o `SGBD`, a `query` para o `SQL Server`, por exemplo, ficaria assim:

```
UPDATE dest
   SET dest.nome = ori.nome
  FROM destino dest
       INNER JOIN origem ori ON ori.cpf = dest.cpf
```

Alguns exemplos de utilização do `INNER JOIN` estão disponíveis no artigo [**Microsoft TechNet: Usando junções internas**](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms190014(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Para SGBD Oracle:

```
    UPDATE destino dest
       SET dest.nome = NVL((SELECT ori.nome
                              FROM origem ori
                             WHERE ori.cpf = dest.cpf), dest.nome);
```

Comment: O problema da sua solução é que, caso não haja ninguém na origem com o mesmo `CPF`, o campo será atualizado com `null`

Comment: Atualizei meu código, adicionado um NVL, prevendo o retorno nulo do SELECT.